# Is it possible to highlight a text and to use a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line

In order to install something usually have to run some commands. In order to make it quicker, could I highlight some command text on the internet I want to run in terminal, then press a keyboard shortcut and run it?

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to. Where would the output from the command go? How would you know if there are errors? What if the command required further input?

Comment: Well I guess it would have to open a terminal to do it so you would see feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sequence can do this:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy to clipboard)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Open a terminal)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste from clipboard)

If you're confident in your highlighting abilities, you could probably shorten that to:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Open a terminal)
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (Paste from selection clipboard)

But is there one shortcut that does all this? No, not by default.

Comment: You said by default, but is there a way to install something to do it?

Comment: Sure. A browser extension seems like the most likely bet: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/terminalrun/

Comment: That addon looks nice but it won't install because says that it is not compatible with most recent firefox.

Comment: Possibly even quicker is to use Oli's second suggestion, but instead of using Shift+Insert, just middle-click in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's how you could do it:

Install the xclip(1) application. It's a standard app, but not installed by default.

Write a short shell script that contains

```
xclip -o | your_command
```

Go to the keyboard settings app > Application Shortcuts and create a new shortcut that runs your script.

I'm afraid I don't know how to make your app run from a terminal. That's left as an exercise for the reader.